# How to change color of CListCtrl column

Tags: c++, mfc, clistctrl

I want to change the background color of a specific column to a color of the dialog (grey). How can I achive it?

```
void CUcsOpTerminalDlg::OnCustomdrawFeatureList(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
{
  LPNMCUSTOMDRAW pNMCD = reinterpret_cast<LPNMCUSTOMDRAW>(pNMHDR);

  // TODO: change color 

  *pResult = 0;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: take a look at the MSDN article [Using Custom Draw](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff919573(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Another link, with explanations, examples, etc: [Neat Stuff to Do in List Controls Using Custom Draw](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/79/Neat-Stuff-to-Do-in-List-Controls-Using-Custom-Dra)

Comment: this method draws only cells for added items. I need to color the whole column, e.g. all cells of a column even they are empty

Comment: @alex555 You have to paint the background of the CListCtrl, then. I think this is done in OnEraseBkgnd. And you have to figure out the width of the column, so you can draw the right rect with the color you want.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the "new" MFC Feature Pack classes (VS 2008 SP1 and up), you can use CMFCListCtrl instead of CListCtrl and use [CMFCListCtrl::OnGetCellBkColor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb984092.aspx).

You would have to derive your own class from it and override [CMFCListCtrl::OnGetCellBkColor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb984092.aspx). There, just check the column index and return the background color you need:

```
COLORREF CMyColorfulListCtrl::OnGetCellBkColor(int nRow,int nColumn)
{
    if (nColumn == THE_COLUMN_IM_INTERESTED_IN)
    {
        return WHATEVER_COLOR_I_NEED;
    }
    return CMFCListCtrl::OnGetCellBkColor(nRow, nColumn);
}
```

Or, if you need the dialog to make the decission, you can query the dialog from that function:

```
COLORREF CMyColorfulListCtrl::OnGetCellBkColor(int nRow,int nColumn)
{
    COLORREF color = GetParent()->SendMessage(UWM_QUERY_ITEM_COLOR, nRow, nColumn);

    if ( color == ((COLORREF)-1) ) 
    { // If the parent doesn't set the color, let the base class decide
        color = CMFCListCtrl::OnGetCellBkColor(nRow, nColumn);
    }    
    return color;
}
```

Note that UWM_QUERY_ITEM_COLOR is a custom message. I usually use Registered Windows Messages [as explained here](http://www.flounder.com/messages.htm).

Comment: Do this method set the color for each cell in the column?

Comment: Only the ones with items. It's custom-draw in disguise. In fact, where there are no items, there are no "cells", so I think, as I said in another comment, that you have to paint the background of the control if you want to change the color of the column where there are no items.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Fill the clrText and clrText Bk fields in the CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT phase.

Best article I ever read about this.
[Part 1](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/controls/listview/customdrawing/article.php/c4195/Custom-Draw-ListView-Controls-Part-I.htm), [Part 2](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/controls/listview/customdrawing/article.php/c4199/Custom-Draw-ListView-Controls-Part-II.htm)

Answer (score 0):

The custom draw API does not work exactly as advertised. Anyway, the following code will paint the second column green:

```
LPNMLVCUSTOMDRAW pNMLVCD = reinterpret_cast<LPNMLVCUSTOMDRAW>(pNMHDR);
*pResult = CDRF_DODEFAULT;
switch( pNMLVCD->nmcd.dwDrawStage )
{
case CDDS_PREPAINT:
    *pResult = CDRF_NOTIFYITEMDRAW;
    break;

case CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT:
    *pResult = CDRF_NOTIFYSUBITEMDRAW;
    break;

case CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT | CDDS_SUBITEM:
    if( pNMLVCD->iSubItem == 1 )
        pNMLVCD->clrTextBk = RGB(0,255,0);
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For any poor soul still struggling to get this to work in 2022, this is the correct answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19701300/5117411

However you MUST ALSO change the first line of your message map declaration in your derived list class, from:

`BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(VV_Page_List_Box, CListCtrl)`

to

`BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(VV_Page_List_Box, CMFCListCtrl)`

otherwise your virtual override for `OnGetCellBkColor` will not get called!