# Set background cell color on CListCtrl

Tags: visual-c++, colors, mfc, clistctrl

I have a table in project :

[image]

Now I want to make some of rows colored, so I tried

```
SetTextBkColor(RGB(122,0,122))
```

The previous line is in the following context:

```
BOOL SickLeaveViewPreviousTab::OnInitDialog()
{

    BOOL result = CDialog::OnInitDialog();

    setHighlighted();

    listCtrl.InsertColumn(0,"Name",LVCFMT_CENTER,80);
    listCtrl.InsertColumn(1,"Surname",LVCFMT_CENTER,120);
    listCtrl.ShowGrid();

    for (int x=0;x<_previous->length();++x)
    {
        shared_ptr<SickLeave> sickLeave = _previous->get(x);
        listCtrl.InsertItem(x,_patient->getName().c_str());
        listCtrl.SetItemText(x,1,_patient->getSurname().c_str());           
        listCtrl.SetTextBkColor(RGB(122,0,122));
    }
    UpdateLayout();
    ReleaseResources();
    return result;
}
```

But the color of the rows doesn't change. How can I solve the problem?

P.S. Yeah, there is a mistake in "desease"...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change color of CListCtrl column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19682479/how-to-change-color-of-clistctrl-column)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question is on https://stackoverflow.com/a/19701300/383779

Derive a made-by-you class from `CMFCListCtrl` which in turn is derived from `CListCtrl`. Then override the method `OnGetCellBkColor` the way want.

```
COLORREF CMyColorfulListCtrl::OnGetCellBkColor(int nRow,int nColumn)
{
    if (nRow == THE_ROW_IM_INTERESTED_IN)
    {
        return WHATEVER_COLOR_I_NEED;
    }
    return CMFCListCtrl::OnGetCellBkColor(nRow, nColumn);
}
```